# How to put data in remote geoserver?

Tags: postgis, geoserver, boundless-suite

I created some layers and upload it to PostGIS and then GeoServer and then styled it using GeoExplorer. I have done all this in localhost. I used the iframe generated in GeoExplorer and used it in my webpage. So I can open it in my computer. But I don't understand how to keep this in remote server so that everyone can access it. 
I used OpenGeoSuite for doing all this.
Is the data I uploaded in PostGIS and GeoServer just located in my computer or in remote server? Please help!!

### Question Extension

This is the code that I am trying to run. But it's not working even in the same machine:

```
var map;

function init() {
   map = new OpenLayers.Map('map_element', {});


   var road_name = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
            "IIRS:river_canal_project - Tiled",
"http://localhost:8080/geoserver/IIRS/wms",
            {
                LAYERS: 'IIRS:river_canal_project',
                STYLES: '',
                format: format,
                tiled: true,
                tilesOrigin : map.maxExtent.left + ',' + map.maxExtent.bottom
            },
            {
                buffer: 0,
                displayOutsideMaxExtent: true,
                isBaseLayer: false,
                yx : {'EPSG:4326' : true}
            } 
        );

   Var industrial_park = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
            "IIRS:future_industrial_project - Tiled", 
"http://localhost:8080/geoserver/IIRS/wms",
            {
                LAYERS: 'IIRS:future_industrial_project',
                STYLES: '',
                format: format,
                tiled: true,
                tilesOrigin : map.maxExtent.left + ',' + map.maxExtent.bottom
            },
            {
                buffer: 0,
                displayOutsideMaxExtent: true,
                isBaseLayer: false,
                yx : {'EPSG:4326' : true}
            } 
        );

   var land_use = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
            "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/IIRS/wms",
            {
                LAYERS: 'IIRS:current_landuse_project',
                STYLES: '',
                format: format
            },
            {
               singleTile: true, 
               ratio: 1, 
               isBaseLayer: true,
               yx : {'EPSG:4326' : true}
            } 
        );
   map.addLayers([land_use, industrial_park, road_name]);
   if(!map.getCenter()){
       map.zoomToMaxExtent();
   }
}
```

Along with the code, I inserted openlayers.js in script and only that.
I found myself some mistakes and now I that can load the map but..the images are not loading.
This is my edited code :

```
map = new OpenLayers.Map('map_element', {});            
            // setup tiled layer
            var tiled = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
                "earth:ne_10m_railroads - Tiled",      
"http://localhost:8080/geoserver/earth/wms",
                {
                    LAYERS: 'earth:ne_10m_railroads',
                    STYLES: '',
                    format: OpenLayers.Format.WMSGetFeatureInfo,
                    tiled: true,
                    tilesOrigin : map.maxExtent.left + ',' + map.maxExtent.bottom
                },
                {
                    buffer: 0,
                    displayOutsideMaxExtent: true,
                    isBaseLayer: true,
                    yx : {'EPSG:900913' : false}
                } 
            );


            map.addLayer(tiled);
var bounds = new OpenLayers.Bounds(
                -135.326858520508, -30.5615100860596,
                179.357788085938, 69.604377746582
);


    map.zoomToExtent(bounds);
}
```

Comment: You can use your IP address (instead of localhost) to have others access it.

Comment: so will it change everytime I use a different internet connection?

Comment: if I buy a remote server for hosting, how can I install all these components there? And I previously thought all the data will be uploaded to remote Geoservers...Isn't that right then. If it is, it will be easy for me.

Comment: It depends how your network is set up. You will need to have a static IP address (rather than DHPC http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol) - I use Oracle Virtual Box on the same PC/Laptop just using static IP

Comment: See: http://www.coretechnologies.com/products/AlwaysUp/Apps/RunVirtualBoxAsAService.html

Comment: @Mapperz thank you..I will try! and one more question, as I said I used the iframe generated in  GeoExplorer in my website..but I want to customize my map in a different way and I can do it using OpenLayers..but I tried in OpenLayers by adding the layer code generated in preview in GeoServer. But it didn't work. it is something like tiled and untiled and I changed the names from tiled to different names and created and added different layers similarly. But no map is loaded even in the same computer. i will post my code here. Please tell me because I need to customise it.

Comment: I use the settings in the virtual box to map a drive to the local pc or vice-versa - see http://operating-systems.wonderhowto.com/how-to/share-local-drives-and-folders-using-oracle-vm-virtualbox-with-guest-windows-os-0126237/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Answer depends on what you mean by remote server.

Ideally, you would have a server connected to the internet (or maybe intranet only, dependent on your need). You would then install the OpenGeo suite on it, and copy your data into the Postgresql database on the Server.

You would then configure Geoserver to serve this data as WMS/WFS services, just like you have done on your development machine.

After this you would copy your JavaScript Application onto a webserver on that server, making sure that it is pointing to the geoserver on that machine, and is accessible from clients.

Comment: I used OpenGeoSuite account for GeoServer and GeoExplorer...and there is no option anywhere how to publish it to remote GeoServer or even if I connected to internet and IIS Serveices enabled, I can't open it in other computer. It says webpage can not be loaded. I think there is someother way!

Comment: OpenGeoSuite is a server product. You are supposed to install it on the server. You could install it on your machine for development purposes,but you need a similar setup for the deployment/production server.

Comment: oh..I understand now..but even if I want to use my machine as server, my doubt is the link or the iframe it generated doesn't have any unique address...then how can it open and also it is not opening. For suppose here is the link and right now I shut down my OpenGeoSuite so I dont think it will     work but see the address once...anybody can generated a similar address.

Comment: "http://localhost:8080/cssteap/viewer/#maps/2"

Comment: The first step is to access it using the server name. so your link should be http://<serverName>:8080/cssteap/viewer.. Then your system needs to be on the network. Only after that can people access the application using the Link. And Yes, your OpenGeo Suite needs to be running.